# Convert string to a formated date in java

Tags: java, parsing, date

Hi, I have a string like:

```
String selectedDate = "Fri Jan 17 00:00:00 CAT 2014";
```

I need to format it to:

```
DD.MM.YYYY = 17.01.2014 00:00:00
```

Can anyone help please see code below:

```
String  date = getDate(selectedDate);

private String getDate(String inpuDate) {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss ").parse(inputDate);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(date);
}
```

Comment: What do you think `mm` is? Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis mm is month

Comment: That's wrong. But regardless, look at your pattern. You have `mm` twice. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @21stking So `mm` is both month and minute? Interesting.

Comment: Month is MM. Look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text

Comment: Why do you think that `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss "` would parse `"Fri Jan 17 00:00:00 CAT 2014"`? Do they look like similar formats???

Comment: Thank you all for the correction! mm = minutes and MM = Month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String  date = getDate(selectedDate);

private String getDate(String inpuDate) {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(inputDate);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(date);
}
```

Comment: Accepting this answer would be nice ;)

Comment: i just did. I clicked on the arrow facing upwards, is that how you do it? :)

Comment: Nope, it's the checkmark ;)